# Calculation of some fields depending on the user's input in Netezza SQL

Tags: sql, netezza

I am coding in Netezza and need to figure out how to use the Fiscal Period entered by the user at runtime to determine where to stop the TSL calculation.

Example: If we run today (June is Fiscal Period 9), and we enter FY 2020 and Period 7 (April) then the 'Amount' calculation would only include the sum of TSLVT + TSL01 + TSL02 + TSL03 + TSL04 + TSL05 + TSL06 + TSL07. Under this scenario, the calculation would need to explicitly leave out Periods 8 and 9 (exclude TSL08 and TSL09) so that we get the FY20 Amount through Period 7.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: It sounds to me that you need a TIME dimension to aid you in these calculations.... please provide sample input and desired output....